# WindowsIdentity always returning the same user regardless who signs in

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-identity

I am running an application on a secure server (I have to remote in and have to email files to someone for them to put them onto the server, so making changes in code is not a quick process).

At one point the service grabs the logged-in user via

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

which worked just fine before, but now, regardless if I sign in or if my colleague signs in, the user is Always the same (some generic xyz user). This user also happens to be the same user that is set up so we can access virtual directories on the site. Coincidence?

[image]

The system was working just fine until a 3rd party or other mysterious entities (i.e. gremlins) went into the system and changed things.

This is a development environment so I can change many things without consequence. There is a development environment with similar code that works just fine (returns proper logged in user), but that system is IIS6, not IIS 7, so trying to find corresponding properties and settings has been... difficult.

How can find the cause of the issue? Or, what things can cause this issue?

Note:
Authentication mode and impersonation is turned on in web.config and seems to be turned on for that specific web application

[image]

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="True" />
```

Comment: First thing I would check is the app pool running the application in question, and check the "Load User Profile" option - see if its changed. Think in your case is should be "False" or it would possibly always return the identity of the account running the app pool.

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913765/trying-to-obtain-windows-username-of-the-client-using-wcf

Comment: @Matt unfortunately that wasn't too helpful :-/

Comment: @DavidW Load User Profile" is set to false

Comment: What does System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() return?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the "Identity" was set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity", instead of "NetworkService", changing that to NetworkService and setting "LoadUserProfile" to TRUE solved the issue.